# When i click back on django root url it gives error page not found

Tags: django, django-templates

Hello everyone i face problem in djnago ,When i click back on root url,in urls.py it give error page not found.plz answer my question quickly.

I only add html template in djnago, all pages works properly but when we click back on root url it give error of page not found

Comment: Please supply your code.